# Get actual project directory of Gitlab

Tags: laravel, nginx, server, gitlab, document-root

I'll straight to my point. I have an machine which installed gitlab and nginx, and I have an fresh laravel project that already has commited, but I need to access the source code of "public" directory of laravel for my nginx. how to get source code of public directory, so I can put into line "root path" in files "sites-enabled" nginx, so nginx can access those files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitLab API doesn't expose the filesystem location directly so you need to stitch the url together.

To get the entry point of all your repositories check you GitLab configuration. (Normally `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`). Find the key `gitlab_git_http_server['repo_root']`.

In there you will see folders which represent your namespaces in these folders are your project.